# Free service similar to 2static.it?

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, static-content

I have a domain with a wordpress install which sets up global cookies.

I'm trying to decrease page load times by having a static subdomain to serve up images and javascript. Unfortunately I cannot use static.mydomain.com because of the global cookies that wordpress uses.

I read some recommendations for 2static.it for this problem, but the site seems to be stopping public registrations at the moment. So is there any viable alternative?

Thanks, and sorry if this is the wrong place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt any free site will provide for serving static content without limitations.

You could setup another domain using apache2 virtual server option and host your static content on that server.

Or, you could explore Amazon AWS, specifically their S3 and CloudFront offerings.

With a CDN you will be able to not only serve static content from a cookie-less domain but also reduce latency and distribute http queries to different servers.